# how to identify http response belongs to which particular request through python?

Tags: python, proxy

I am trying to write my own proxy extensions. Both, burp suite as well as mitmproxy allows us to write extensions.

Till now, I am successful with intercepting the request and response headers, and write it to my own output file.

The problem is, I get frequent requests and responses at anonymous time and at the same time, the output is getting written in the file.

How should I identify that which response belongs to which particular request ??

If we see in burp suite, when we click on particulat URL in target, we see two different tabs- "Request" and "Response". How is burp suite identifying this ? 
Similar is the case with mitmproxy.

I am new to proxy extensions, so any help would be great.

----EDIT----
If any additional information is required then pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In mitmproxy 0.10, a flow object is passed to the response handler function. You can access both flow.request and flow.response.

Comment: @mhils- Thanks for reply. I am working on something else right now. I will get back to you as soon as I switch to this task. :)